# Animating a bomb that explodes at a certain keyframe after cell fracture

Tags: animation, mesh, physics

Okay, so I'm trying to create a bomb using cell fracture.  I've got it fractured and set as an active object in physics.  I've set the animation to have it flying through the air which is all good.  I've grouped each "cell" together but when I animate the "Dynamic" button on the active "cell," it does not insert the keyframe for each of the others in the group; not even after clicking the "Copy from selected" button in the physics tool shelf.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what I've figured out is that after creating my group, I had to set up the animated "Dynamic" box for when I wanted it inactive and when I wanted it active again.  After all animation had been set up, I hit ctrl+L > Animation Data and that did the trick!  Now the explosion takes place at the frame I wanted.

The key is to set all of the animations for the active member of the group BEFORE making the link to the Animation Data!

Maybe this will help others as well!

Comment: hey, maybe you should select your answer as the one you needed(check it) so people know the question is answered.